# module level code run twice when patching

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock, patch

Consider the following simple code:

**test_code.py**

```
def f():
    return 'unpatched'

import patch_stuff

patch_stuff.patch_it_up()
print f()
```

**patch_stuff.py**

```
from mock import patch

def patch_it_up():
    p = patch('test_code.f')
    m = p.start()
    m.return_value = 'patched'
```

I would expect the output of running `python test_code.py` to be

```
patched
```

however the output is:

```
unpatched
patched
```

**How come?**

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code. First, the **test_code.py** file is called twice - first when you call it, and then again when `mock` imports it for the purpose of creating a patch. So you should change it as follows:

```
def f():
    return 'unpatched'

import patch_stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patch_stuff.patch_it_up()
    print f()
```

This will print only the `'unpatched'` string. Which leads to the second thing: [the documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/mock-1.0.1.pdf) suggests that this not how the patchers work. When you call the `start` method it returns the patched object to be used. So the expected output can be achieved with the following modifications:

**patch_stuff.py**

```
from mock import patch

def patch_it_up():
    p = patch('test_code.f')
    m = p.start()
    m.return_value = 'patched'
    return m
```

**test_code.py**

```
def f():
    return 'unpatched'

import patch_stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = patch_stuff.patch_it_up()
    print m()
```

This will print the expected `'patched'` string.

---

This makes this scenario not very practical, but all the examples in the documentation show only the possibility of modifying modules imported in the current context. E.g., this will also work:

```
from mock import patch

def patch_it_up():
    import test_code
    p = patch('test_code.f')
    m = p.start()
    m.return_value = 'patched'
    print "inside patch_it_up:", test_code.f()
```